# Cannot Run GUI AppleScripts

Tags: applescript, ui

I recently upgraded my system to OS X 10.11 El Capitan and ever since, my AppleScript which enables GUI scripting cannot be run. Part of the reason is obvious, the Universal Access pane in System Preferences has changed, i.e. there is no longer a checkbox to enable it. I would like to know how do I enable it in this newer system?

I found a shell script, which is supposed to work with Yosemite, but it does not work with my system. Anyone have an idea? I would think it would not be necessary to use the shell. Isn't there some way to click on some checkbox and, if necessary, enter your system password?

Answer (score 1):

OK, it's kind of embarrasing, in a way, when you figure out the answer to your own question, but, here it is:

You just go to the Security and Privacy pane, click on the Privacy tab, and then add the apps where you want to allow GUI scripting. Just that simple....

Answer (score 0):

There is not.  Individual applications are now given access to the Accessibility features, there is no global control.

As you can see there is a + icon to allow you to add an application.  You can also have your script add itself.

Another method: http://www.macosautomation.com/mavericks/guiscripting/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Marc, as you can see below, I figured it out on my own. Thanks again.